# Corrupted file after uploading througth curl

Tags: php, rest, curl, file-upload, php-7

I want to upload image file. Target is REST api endpoint with oAuth2 autohization. I managed to upload something but when I open file on server it's corrupted. Size didn't match with source file.

This is code that I use:

```
<?php
$file = 'example.jpg';

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$finfo = finfo_file($finfo, __DIR__.'/'.$file);

$ending = "\r\n";

$boundary = md5(microtime());
$fullBoundary = sprintf("--%s%s", $boundary, $ending);

$body = '';
$body .= $fullBoundary;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"$file\"".$ending;
$body .= "Content-Type: $finfo".$ending;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$ending.$ending;
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/'.$file))).$ending;
$body .= "--".$boundary."--".$ending.$ending;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt(
    $ch,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    [
        'Authorization: Bearer token...',
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=".$boundary,
    ]
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.example.com/upload");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/1.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0');
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
print_r($curl_response);
curl_close($ch);
```

Can anyone help me with that?

P.S. I forget to say that I tried using "@" notation, and \CurlFile but then the $_FILES array was empty that's why I created whole request body manually.

Answer (score 1):

After some time I managed to make this work with this:

```
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: multipart/form-data".$ending.$ending;
$body .= file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/'.$file).$ending;
```

Now file is visible on server side and it's not corrupted but this still doesn't answer why "normal" way don't work. It would be great if someone could explain what's is going on here :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for `curlopt_postfields`:

> To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The
>   filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with
>   the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be
>   passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as
>   an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value
>   is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to
>   multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files
>   are passed to this option with the @ prefix. As of PHP 5.5.0, the @
>   prefix is deprecated and files can be sent using CURLFile. The @
>   prefix can be disabled for safe passing of values beginning with @ by
>   setting the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option to TRUE.

Try sending the file like this.

```
$file = 'example.jpg';
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$finfo = finfo_file($finfo, __DIR__.'/'.$file);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@'.realpath($file).';filename='.basename($file).';type='.$finfo));
curl_setopt(
    $ch,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    [
        'Authorization: Bearer token...',
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=".$boundary,
    ]
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.example.com/upload");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/1.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0');
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
print_r($curl_response);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it in the question, I'm using PHP 7.1 and as far as I know this notation is no longer supported. I tried \CurlFile but then $_FILES array was empty on server-side

Comment: @Vail what evidence do you have to support that theory. If it was deprecated in 7 the docs would have noted it, which they did not. This is how its done.

Comment: Well, I cannot find the place where I read that this notation don't work in PHP7 but it's definitely deprecated. Even in fragment you pasted above they mentioning it: "As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files can be sent using CURLFile. The @ prefix can be disabled for safe passing of values beginning with @ by setting the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option to TRUE."

Comment: @Vail - Good catch, thank you. I'll delete this post as soon as I can.